# Magento 2, issue with getting "version" number in file paths

Tags: magento2, theme, deploy

Not my first time to install Magento 2, but something strange this time. I have checked file permission, cleaned cache, deployed again. Files are created in pub/static in expected directories but checking browser console I see there is "version###" subdirectory in  path. How this is happening?

[image]

Comment: Stores>Configuration>Advanced>Developer>Sign Static Files

Comment: @KhoaTruongDinh, I can't do that, as theme is not loading properly, save config button does not work

Comment: @KhoaTruongDinh, can it be done directly in db? if yes do you know what table?

Comment: `insert into core_config_data (config_id, scope, scope_id, path, value) values (null, 'default', 0, 'dev/static/sign', 0); `

Comment: @KhoaTruongDinh, tnx, it worked, pls create solution

Comment: this solved my problem with development version number add to path urls prevented .js files from loading. Does disabling have any adverse effects, as adobe recommend this left set to yes? thanks

Answer (score 18, accepted):

We can disable it in Admin:

> Stores > Configuration > Advanced > Developer > Sign Static Files

Or we can change directly the value in `core_config_data`:

```
insert into core_config_data (config_id, scope, scope_id, path, value) values (null, 'default', 0, 'dev/static/sign', 0);
```

Answer (score 6):

Run the following commands and you will see static version number in the static URLs (CSS, JS etc.)

```
bin/magento config:set dev/static/sign 1

bin/magento cache:clean

bin/magento cache:flush
```

Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 1):

1)Run SQL query on DB (to disable Sign Static Files)

```
insert into core_config_data (config_id, scope, scope_id, path, value) values (null, 'default', 0, 'dev/static/sign', 0);
```

2)After That clean and Flush Magento Cache

```
bin/magento cache:clean
bin/magento cache:flush
```

And Refresh the page

Comment: UPDATE `core_config_data` SET `value` = '0' WHERE `core_config_data`.`path` = 'dev/static/sign';

Answer (score 0):

Follow this link and go to the line

```
https://www.simicart.com/blog/how-to-install-magento-2-localhost/

Additional tweaks for Magento 2.4.2 and above
```

you may get error in css and js path then you run

```
sudo rm -rf pub/static
sudo rm -rf var/cache
sudo rm -rf var/composer_home
sudo rm -rf var/generation
sudo rm -rf var/page_cache
sudo rm -rf var/view_preprocessed
```

and run

```
sudo php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
```

and run

```
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

Done.

Answer (score 0):

Happened to me few times. so I'll add another one to check

All of the above and make sure you have .htaccess in your pub/static folder