# Magento 2 css js all can't be loaded after upgrade

Tags: magento2, javascript, css

After i upgraded the magento 2 from 2.1 to 2.1.5, all can't be loaded

All css & javascript links are like this

```
http://example.com/pub/static/version1491232244/frontend/Magento/luma/en_US/css/styles-l.css
```

with version1491232244, the path is wrong, if i remove version1491232244, the resource can be loaded, anyone know what is the problem?

it seems the nginx rewrite problem?

My current config:

```
    location /static/ {
            # Uncomment the following line in production mode
            # expires max;

            # Remove signature of the static files that is used to overcome the browser cache
            location ~ ^/static/version {
                    rewrite ^/static/(version\d*/)?(.*)$ /static/$2 last;
            }

            location ~* \.(ico|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|svg|js|css|swf|eot|ttf|otf|woff|woff2)$ {
                    add_header Cache-Control "public";
                    add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
                    expires +1y;

                    if (!-f $request_filename) {
                            rewrite ^/static/(version\d*/)?(.*)$ /static.php?resource=$2 last;
                    }
            }

            location ~* \.(zip|gz|gzip|bz2|csv|xml)$ {
                    add_header Cache-Control "no-store";
                    add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
                    expires    off;

                    if (!-f $request_filename) {
                       rewrite ^/static/(version\d*/)?(.*)$ /static.php?resource=$2 last;
                    }
            }

            if (!-f $request_filename) {
                    rewrite ^/static/(version\d*/)?(.*)$ /static.php?resource=$2 last;
            }

            add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
    }
```

Comment: Does the value in /versionXXXX/ matches value in `$MAGENTO_ROOT/pub/static/deployed_version.txt`, you can try going to `http://youdomain.com/static/deployed_version.txt`

Comment: You can try to disable static files versioning in `Stores > Configuration > Advanced > Developers > Static Files Settings > Sign Static Files`

Comment: i've checked the value is not match, but i changed the right number it  is still 404

Comment: Take a look here: http://magento.stackexchange.com/a/162210/33057