# Multi website frontend page is broken after upgrading to 2.3.3

Tags: css, magento-2.2.5, magento2.3.3, magento-upgrade, static-content

I have a Magento 2 multi-website with each website has their own store view, after I upgrade it from 2.5 to 2.3.3, the main website is looking fine, but the others are broken and when I inspect, got an error like this:

```
(index):1 Refused to apply style from 'pub/static/_cache/merged/0cb08dac7714064caf47f5c9bb91fcb6.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.
```

[image]

*** I already deleted the pub/static/frontend and make sure the pub/static/.htaccess is there, and run:***

```
bin/magento cache:clean
bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
```

but still got the same error

Comment: All other website has same locale?

Comment: yes @DJDev using same locale

Comment: check the static files of which errors are thrown are present on the desired location or missing?

Comment: can you run the upgrade, di:compile and then run the static-content:deploy

Comment: @ASQ yes the file is exist in server pub/static folder

Comment: @venkataprasad still same error

Comment: check the permissions of pub folder

Answer (score 1):

Your versioning is enabled due to this it is looking like that.
So please run the following SQL query for the **core_config table**.

```
insert into core_config_data (config_id, scope, scope_id, path, value) values (null, 'default', 0, 'dev/static/sign', 0);
```

And run deploy command

```
bin/magento cache:clean
bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
```

Give permission if required to var, generated and pub/static

For more information please check that reference for versioning issues.

[Disable Versioning Magento 2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/162205/magento-2-issue-with-getting-version-number-in-file-paths)

Comment: i already has this configuration , and its still the same error

Comment: rename the static directory inside the pub and run the deploy command.

Give permission to pub/static once deploy command run succesfully

Answer (score 0):

Run this command:

```
bin/magento cache:clean
bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
```

And after **-f**, add **lang** corresponding with each of your website